# How to keep an Android grpc client with server streaming connection alive?

Tags: android, kotlin, grpc, grpc-java

I have a grpc-js server and a Kotlin for Android client that makes a server streaming call. This is the GRPCService class.

```kotlin
class GRPCService {
    private val mChannel = ManagedChannelBuilder
        .forAddress(GRPC_HOST_ADDRESS, GRPC_HOST_PORT)
        .usePlaintext()
        .keepAliveTime(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .keepAliveWithoutCalls(true)
        .build()
    val asyncStub : ResponderServiceGrpc.ResponderServiceStub = 
        ResponderServiceGrpc.newStub(mChannel)
}
```

And the method is called from a foreground service.

```kotlin
override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    ...
    startForeground(MyNotificationBuilder.SERVICE_NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.getServiceNotification())
}
override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
    val userId = sharedPreferencesManager.getInt(SharedPreferencesManager.USER_ID)
    val taskRequest = Responder.TaskRequest.newBuilder()
        .setUserId(userId)
        .build()

    grpcService.asyncStub.getTasks(taskRequest, object :
        StreamObserver<Responder.TaskResponse> {
        override fun onCompleted() {
            Log.d("grpc Tasks", "Completed")
        }

        override fun onError(t: Throwable?) {
            Log.d("grpc error cause", t?.cause.toString())
            t?.cause?.printStackTrace()
            Log.d("grpc error", "AFTER CAUSE")
            t!!.printStackTrace()
        }

        override fun onNext(value: Responder.TaskResponse?) {
            if (value != null) {
            
                when (value.command) {
                   ...
                }
            }
        }
    })
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)
}
```

The connection opens and stays open for about a minute of no communication and then fails with the following error.

```
D/grpc error cause: null
D/grpc error: AFTER CAUSE
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INTERNAL: Internal error
io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:533)
io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$StreamObserverToCallListenerAdapter.onClose(ClientCalls.java:460)
io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:426)
io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$500(ClientCallImpl.java:66)
io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.close(ClientCallImpl.java:689)
io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.access$900(ClientCallImpl.java:577)
io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInternal(ClientCallImpl.java:751)
io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:740)
io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123)
```

The grpc-js server is created with the following options.

```
var server = new grpc.Server({
    "grpc.http2.min_ping_interval_without_data_ms" : 10000,
    "grpc.keepalive_permit_without_calls" : true,
    "grpc.http2.min_time_between_pings_ms" : 10000,
    "grpc.keepalive_time_ms" : 10000,
    "grpc.http2.max_pings_without_data" : 0,
    'grpc.http2.min_ping_interval_without_data_ms':  5000
});
```

I never received the `too many pings` error either.

I noticed that if there is periodic communication (like the server pinging the client with a small amount of data every 30s or so) through this connection then I don't get the error and the connection stays open for as long as the pinging continues (tested for 2 days).

How do I keep the connection open without resorting to periodically pinging the client?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The managed channel has a property called keepAliveWithoutCalls which has a default value of false as seen [here](https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/ManagedChannelBuilder.html#keepAliveWithoutCalls-boolean-). If this is not set to true then the keepAlive will not happen if there are no current active calls happening. You would need to set this like so:

```
private val mChannel = ManagedChannelBuilder
    .forAddress(GRPC_HOST_ADDRESS, GRPC_HOST_PORT)
    .usePlaintext()
    .keepAliveTime(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .keepAliveWithoutCalls(true)
    .build()
```

There is a possibility that you will have to do some other settings on the server as well to have the connection stay open without any data passing. You might get an error on the server saying "too many pings". This happens because there are some other settings GRPC needs. I am not sure exactly how to achieve this with a JS server but it shouldn't be too difficult. These settings include:

```
GRPC_ARG_HTTP2_MIN_RECV_PING_INTERVAL_WITHOUT_DATA_MS
Minimum allowed time between a server receiving successive ping frames without sending any data/header/window_update frame.
```

And this one:

```
GRPC_ARG_HTTP2_MIN_SENT_PING_INTERVAL_WITHOUT_DATA_MS
Minimum time between sending successive ping frames without receiving any data/header/window_update frame, Int valued, milliseconds.
```

And this one:

```
GRPC_ARG_KEEPALIVE_PERMIT_WITHOUT_CALLS
Is it permissible to send keepalive pings without any outstanding streams.
```

There is a [Keepalive User Guide for gRPC](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/keepalive.md) which I suggest you read through to understand how gRPC should keep connections open. This is the core standard that all server and client implementations should follow, but I have noticed this is not always the case. You can have a look at a previous but similar question I asked a while back [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53866254/grpc-android-client-losing-connection-too-many-pings).

Comment: Thanks for the well structured answer. I edited my question accordingly but the error remains. I looked through all the links you provided and incorporated it into my code where applicable. I never got the `too many pings` error. It has always been the one above. I originally tested my server using a grpc-js client and I receive the same error there.

Comment: Just to make sure, you are not using some proxy software such as Nginx or any L7 load balancer in between your JS server and Android client? These could have their own timeouts and connection cleanup configs.

Comment: I do. I am using Nginx to forward communication on my GRPC port to the GRPC server. I did not think about that. Let me look into that as well. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Since Nginx is a L7 proxy, the underlying L4 TCP connections are terminated at Nginx. This means that you would need to configure Nginx to keep your connection open to match the gRPC spec. Since gRPC uses Http2. You may need to check a bunch of configs on the Nginx side to make sure its configured correctly. I have never used a http2 proxy to be honest.

Comment: What I meant to say is Nginx doesn't "forward ports". It actually inspects the underlying traffic on the http/http2 protocol and makes decisions such as which host to forward.

Comment: Really thanks a lot. Your comments on Nginx made a big difference. I will post my own answer later just as reference when I have a proper working solution.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the `ManagedChannelBuilder.keepAliveTime` setting  (https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/api/src/main/java/io/grpc/ManagedChannelBuilder.java#L357) ? I am assuming it will work in the middle of a server streaming call.

Comment: thanks for the answer but unfortunately it still fails with the same error after about a minute of inactivity. I have edited the question to reflect my changes and added some more context.